# Xcode keeps using bandwidth when I log into developer account with xcode

Tags: xcode

I recently got a developer account from the company I work for.

When I log into Xcode with that account(or any other developer account) and open the company project xcode process keeps downloading data from developerservices2-rno.apple.com which I found out using wireshark.
as soon as I log out it stops downloading. and it doesn't happen when I open other projects.

this download averages about 1GB per hour and it doens't stop as long as I'm logged into xcode.

Anyone can help me find a solution to this issue?
tried with xcode 12.5 and 13 beta both are same.